# Members Area php session login logout

Tags: php, session, password-protection

I have a Members area in the below model but I am not sure whether it is safe or not. Please tell me your suggestions and opinion on this.

I made a page called members.html and Members area page called members.php

Code inside members.php

```
<?
session_start();


if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 0)
{
include 'members.html';
}  

echo "<br /><a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";

?>
```

In the logout.php

```
<?
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location:home.html");
exit();
?>
```

Is this coding good enough to be called as a password protected page? what should I add to make it more safe?

Thanks!

Edit.......

The coding is not working. I logout out and went to the members page directly and the page is working fine. I am a little confused, please help me with the code.

In the checkuser.php page I have the below sessions,

```
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;

    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;

    $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;

    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
```

and I have the username and password which users entered in variables $username and $password.

Edit..........

I found the below answer and is working for now. But I am not sure this is right or not.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 0){
include 'members.html';
}
}
else
{
header("Location: home.html");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't see where your sessions are being set.  You may also want to use SSL since sessions can be hijacked.

Answer (score 1):

Your members area page looks completely unprotected. I don't see any session checking in the code below. What session variables do logged in users have?

```
<?
session_start();

include 'members.html';

echo "<br /><a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I forget this line. 
if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 0){
 include 'pay.html';
}